# Why won't Weka allow me to start Association Rule generation?

Tags: weka

I have created an arff file for a data set that I would like to use in Weka. The file is formatted as a sparse arff file. Anyway, I have successfully loaded in the data. I then switch to the Association tab and set my parameters. However, the Start button won't become enabled, so I can't click it to start the association generation. Why is this? Has anyone run into this issue before and know how to solve it?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to check the attribute types in your arff file. Weka is very particular about types when they are used for associations and even though it may let you set parameters, the routine will not run.

Try using an attribute declaration like the following:

```
@attribute "attr1" {t}
```

And define your rows as follows:

```
{1957 "t", 9163 "t", 10143 "t"}
```

Comment: Oh, so I had it formatted with 1s and 0s instead of ts and fs. That must be the problem. I will try that out. Thanks.

Comment: Sure enough, that was the problem. The start button is now enabled because valid data is available for association generation. Thanks for your help! I wish Weka wasn't such a fickle piece of software. It has terrible space efficiency too... I keep overrunning my heap!

Answer (score 5):

all variables must be Nominal; is the a priori method does not work on numeric variables